# Prolog path backtracking runs forever depending on grid size

Tags: prolog, wumpus-world

I've written some code to do backtracking in Prolog that generates all the possible paths to reach the Gold cell from the initial one (Agent). The input of getAllPaths is the map size NxN. When I run it with a 6x6 map it works perfectly and prints all the possible paths, but when I input any map size >= 7 it prints the first path and gets stuck there when I require the next possible solution with `;`. Here is my code:

```
gold(3, 3).
agent(1, 1).

getAllPaths(MS) :-
    agent(X, Y),
    assertz(worldSize(MS)),
    getAllPathsRec(X, Y, [], []).

% Positions, Visited list, and Path list
getAllPathsRec(X, Y, V, L) :-
    \+member((X, Y), V), append(V, [(X, Y)], VP),
    ((gold(X, Y), print(L)) ; move(X, Y, VP, L)).

% Left
move(X, Y, V, L) :-
    XP is X - 1, XP > 0,
    append(L, [l], LP),
    getAllPathsRec(XP, Y, V, LP).

% Right
move(X, Y, V, L) :-
    XP is X + 1, worldSize(MS), XP =< MS,
    append(L, [r], LP),
    getAllPathsRec(XP, Y, V, LP).

% Up
move(X, Y, V, L) :-
    YP is Y + 1, worldSize(MS), YP =< MS,
    append(L, [u], LP),
    getAllPathsRec(X, YP, V, LP).

% Down
move(X, Y, V, L) :-
    YP is Y - 1, YP > 0,
    append(L, [d], LP),
    getAllPathsRec(X, YP, V, LP).
```

The output:

```
?- getAllPaths(6).
[r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,u,r,r]
true ;
[r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,u,r,u,l,u,r,r,r,r,r,d,l,l,l,d]
true ;
[r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,u,r,u,l,u,r,r,r,r,r,d,l,l,d,l]
true ;
[...]
?- getAllPaths(7).
[r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,l,u,r,r]
true ;
% It gets stuck here forever...
```

First I thought it would be for some depth recursion limits, but it's so strange because the map size is only incremented from 36 to 49, and I would probably get some warning or error, but it displays nothing. Any clue?

Comment: I haven't tried because there are about `O(n!)` possible paths, but if I try with 3 or 4 (small amount) yes, it finished

Comment: With 3 it outputs 64 possible paths.

Comment: For me, the four are different:
`?- getAllPaths(4).`
`[r,r,r,u,l,l,l,u,r,r], [r,r,r,u,l,l,l,u,r,u,r,r,d,l], [r,r,r,u,l,l,l,u,r,u,r,d], [r,r,r,u,l,l,l,u,u,r,r,r,d,l, [r,r,r,u,l,l,l,u,u,r,r,d]`

Comment: And yes, I'm using SWI-Prolog Version 7.2.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188618/discussion-between-josepjoestar-and-guy-coder).

Answer (score 1):

This code improve the performance.
I think it's a bad design to mix the search and the printing of the result.

```
gold(3, 3).
agent(1, 1).

getAllPaths(MS, L) :-
    agent(X, Y),
    retractall(worldSize(_)),
    assertz(worldSize(MS)),
    getAllPathsRec(X, Y, [], [], L).


% Positions, Visited list, and Path list
getAllPathsRec(X, Y, _V, L, NL) :-
    gold(X, Y),
    reverse(L, NL).


% Positions, Visited list, and Path list
getAllPathsRec(X, Y, V, CL, L) :-
    \+member((X, Y), V),

    % useless 
    % append(V, [(X, Y)], VP),

    move(X, Y, CL, NX, NY, NL),

    % No need to use append to build the list of visited nodes
    getAllPathsRec(NX, NY, [(X,Y) | V], NL, L).

% Left
move(X, Y, L, NX, Y, [l|L]) :-
    X > 1 ,NX is X - 1.

% Right
move(X, Y, L, NX, Y, [r|L]) :-
    worldSize(MS), X < MS,NX is X + 1.

% Up
move(X, Y, L, X, NY, [u|L]) :-
    worldSize(MS), Y < MS, NY is Y + 1.

% Down
move(X, Y, L, X, NY, [d|L]) :-
    Y > 1, NY is Y - 1.
```

I get :

```
?- getAllPaths(7, V), writeln(V).
[r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,l,u,r,r]
V = [r, r, r, r, r, r, u, l, l|...] ;
[r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,l,u,r,r,r,l]
V = [r, r, r, r, r, r, u, l, l|...] ;
 [r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,l,u,r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,d]
V = [r, r, r, r, r, r, u, l, l|...] ;
[r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,l,u,r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,u,l,l,l,d,r,r,d]
V = [r, r, r, r, r, r, u, l, l|...] ;
[r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,l,u,r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,u,l,l,u,l,d,d,r,r,d]
V = [r, r, r, r, r, r, u, l, l|...] ;
[r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,l,u,r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,u,l,l,u,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,l,d,d,d,r,r,d]
V = [r, r, r, r, r, r, u, l, l|...] ;
[r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,l,u,r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,u,l,l,u,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,d,d,d,r,r,d]
V = [r, r, r, r, r, r, u, l, l|...] ;
[r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,l,l,l,u,r,r,r,r,r,r,u,l,l,l,u,l,l,u,r,r,r,r,d,r,u,u,l,l,l,l,l,l,d,d,d,r,r,d]
V = [r, r, r, r, r, r, u, l, l|...] .
```

Comment: Ok, I get it's a bad design to mix the search and the printing of the result, but do you think that this was the problem of the no-output?

Comment: No, I don't think. if you look at my code you can see that I avoid **append/3** which i quite slow, I remove the calls of **getAllPaths** from the clauses of move, I tried to get it more simple. But if you try **getAllPaths(10, V)** it freeze.

Comment: You mean that the program is working but was soooo slow and unefficient?

Comment: Yes, I think so !

Comment: @joel76 You still have `append(V, [(X, Y)], VP),` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my variation.

```
getAllPaths_01(MS, R) :-
    agent(X, Y),
    getAllPathsRec_01(MS, X, Y, [], R).

getAllPathsRec_01(_MS, X, Y, _V, []) :-
  gold(X,Y), !.

% Positions, Visited list, and Path list
getAllPathsRec_01(MS, X, Y, V, R) :-
    \+ memberchk((X, Y), V),
    move_01(MS, X, Y, [(X, Y)|V], R).

% Left
move_01(MS, X, Y, V, [l|R]) :-
    XP is X - 1, XP > 0,
    getAllPathsRec_01(MS, XP, Y, V, R).

% Right
move_01(MS, X, Y, V, [r|R]) :-
    XP is X + 1, XP =< MS,
    getAllPathsRec_01(MS, XP, Y, V, R).

% Up
move_01(MS, X, Y, V, [u|R]) :-
    YP is Y + 1, YP =< MS,
    getAllPathsRec_01(MS, X, YP, V, R).

% Down
move_01(MS, X, Y, V, [d|R]) :-
    YP is Y - 1, YP > 0,
    getAllPathsRec_01(MS, X, YP, V, R).

count(S,N) :-
  bagof(L,getAllPaths_01(S,L),Ls),
  length(Ls,N).
```

This removes the use [assertz/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assertz/1) so that rerunning the query does not add multiple facts, changes [member/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2) to [memerchk/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=memberchk/2) for efficiency, builds the path upon backtracking to avoid [append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3), and added a cut to remove the duplicate answers.

Since the result is returned to the top level, added count/2 to show the counts instead of the list.

```
?- count(3,N).
N = 12.

?- count(4,N).
N = 132.

?- count(5,N).
N = 6762.

?- count(6,N).
N = 910480
```

Comment: After running out of stack space with 64G for `?- count(7,N).` I stopped trying to get the answer. You can pursue it if you want. It is generating lots of answers, but has to collect them for `bagof` and thus need for the large stack size.